# Spectrum colorpicker not working on jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I'm trying to show the Spectrum colorpicker on a jQuery dialog but it's not showing up. This is the code I'm using for loading spectrum:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#colour").spectrum({color: "#f00" });});
```

Being 'colour' a div inside my jQuery dialog.
This is the code that initializes the dialog:

```
dialogObj = $("#_dialogPanel").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizeable: true,
        position: { my: "center-100 bottom-40", at: "center center" },
        stack: true,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });
    $("#_dialogPanel").submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    dialogObj.dialog("open");
```

The content in the dialog is dynamically loaded using:

```
$("#_dialogPanel").empty().html(response);
$(document).ready(function() { $("#colour").spectrum({color: "#f00" });});
```

Being 'response':

```
<div name='colour' id='colour' />
```

The references to spectrum.js and spectrum.css are added in the master page

Answer (score 1):

Spectrum color picker doesn't work on div, only on input elements

```
<input type='text' id="colour" />
```